Going against traditional rules = "I just want to be me" - hashkafic (and halachic?) analysis
The modern trend is to try to say that any "traditional" restrictions on human expression are no longer enforcible, and in fact, those who defy them are to be celebrated as "being able to truly express themself".
For example, Gonzo in Muppet Babies (a show aimed at children), when he comes out as cross-dressing (something that general society considered an idiosyncrasy until recently), explains his deception by saying:

"I don't want you to be upset with me... but I don't want to do things just because that's the way they've been done, either. I wanna be me."


Question: What do Torah sources say about this concept... specifically, the concept of "being me" being associated with "going against traditional rules"?

Examples of things I've seen that could be relevant:

The question "aren't all the many laws and halachot in Judaism restrictive to a person's freedom?"
The idea of tachlit, tikun, yi'ud - i.e. the person's mission/purpose
The concepts of humility and bittul - "I just want to be me" could be animal soul/yeitzer hara, especially because...
...Avot 6:3: שאין לך בן חורין אלא מי שעוסק בתלמוד תורה
Mesirat Nefesh


There's אל יבוש מפני המלעיגים and כל העולם לא נברא אלא בשבילי and איך בין איך, but they're about inner strength and purpose and authenticity, not nonconformity for its own sake, though even the latter can be a useful catalyst if channeled productively.

VTC, I fail to understand what it is about and how it is related to Jewish Hashkafa.

IMHO, the only concept discussed in Judaism is "how to be a kosher Jew", not how to be me or you. One can think of themselves whatever they want as long as they behave Kosherly.

See the Vilna Gaon quoted in Even Shlema 4:17

The argument for "nonconformity" is that "traditional" rules are human-constructed/promoted, & thus only relevant to specific time/place/culture. Divine rules have no such limitation. If the question is "what place is there for my individuality within the rules?" the answer is, "as large as possible." ותן חלקנו בתורתיך implies each person has their own unique part. It's implicit in the parallel between people's faces and opinions - people's faces differ wildly within a basic shared pattern.

Any societal norm will limit my self-expression in one way or another. For example, a society's wide acceptance of cross-dressing as normal limits my self-expression of the belief that human beings are infinitely more than just what they wear.

Kudos for the first time רב גנזו הגדל has been quoted on this site, @RabbiKaii!

Very tangentially related (pertains to Muppets) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120244/ptij-what-does-cookie-monster-eat-during-pesach

"I don't want to do things just because that's the way they've been done, either" Good thing that's not why religious Jews believe they should follow God's commandments. (That's a common straw-man set up in many depictions of religion in popular secular culture.)

My question isn’t about why Jews follow commandments but about how Judaism views defiance of tradition in the name of self-expression.

@RabbiKaii So things like not wearing white socks because you like the color turquoise? I don't really get what case you're talking about, and it doesn't seem like the answers do either (one talks about punishments for violating God's commandments)

@DoubleAA btw, there is a principle in Jewish thinking for "doing things because that's how our fathers did it". Not the only principle, but a principle nonetheless. Your case of socks could be relevant. N.T.'s quote is good because of the "as my heart sees fit shall I do" part of the quote. Feedback noted though, I will see if I can improve the case. The example case is what I am aiming at most specifically.

@RabbiKaii But the example of not cross-dressing is a commandment and we do it because God said so not "just because that's the way they've been done". Also, taking a small part of a verse out of context is not "good".

@DoubleAA does hashkafa recognise a category of "mitzva violators" who are doing so because "they are being them"? I gave several examples of areas of hashkafa that might be equipped to answer that question.

Depending on the case, Hilchot Teshuvah 3:11 may be relevant.

אַל תִּפְרֹשׁ מִן הַצִּבּוּר

As one can imagine, the Torah is very against such an attitude:

And it be, when he hears the words of this curse that he bless himself in his heart, saying: [These curses will not come upon me, but] "All will be well with me, for as my heart sees fit shall I do," so that the unwitting (sin) is added (for punishment) to the willful,
The L-rd will not wish to forgive him, for then the wrath of the L-rd and His vengeance will burn against that man, and there shall descend upon him the entire curse that is written in this scroll, and the L-rd will erase his name from under the heavens.
And the L-rd will set him aside for evil from all of the tribes of Israel, according to all the curses of the covenant that are written in this scroll of the Torah.


The closest I am aware the Torah comes to this is Mishlei 22:6, which states
"חֲנֹ֣ךְ לַ֭נַּעַר עַל־פִּ֣י דַרְכּ֑וֹ גַּ֥ם כִּי־יַ֝זְקִ֗ין לֹֽא־יָס֥וּר מִמֶּֽנָּה"
Which can be translated as "Train a child according to his way and he will not veer from it in his old age"
This would appear to suggest that "the way it's always been done" may not work for every child, and that by doing things his way, you will give him an education that will last a lifetime.
As always, one should consult a posek before putting anything on this site into practice, and you'd probably want to look at some meforshim there as well. Also, this would clearly not provide a basis to allow something  assur mid'orayta like cross-dressing.

If you understand this in context, it is actually referring to  Chanoch ben Yered who in his “old age” who “walked with G-d” as a perfect Saint and ultimately evolved into the Ministering Angel, Metatron, the youngest of the the Angels and their leader. Because he understood the difficulties of living as a human being, he was better able to interface between Heaven and Earth.

@YaacovDeane That is not "In context" that is in the realm of sod.

@N.T. Actually, it's in the realm of Midrash. The detailed historical account of Chanoch is also discussed in the Sod aspect, but to really understand the story and concept requires learning the midrashim from Chanoch himself. He maintained the tradition that he had received directly from Adam and Shet (Seth). Are you familiar?

@YaacovDeane Are you familiar with the difference between pshat and Remez/drush/sod? Why are you bringing this up at all?

@N.T. Yes, I am familiar with the difference between pshat and the other 3 aspects you mention. According to Rashi and others, the Pshat includes and encompasses all the other 3 aspects. Like the language from Mishlei quoted in this answer, it is clearly alluding to Chanoch & his transition to the Angelic state. Understanding that historical paradigm clarifies what the educational and developmental process is that Shlomo is discussing. Shlomo HaMelech was referencing the details from Sefer Chanoch. It is not Sod. It is from the revealed aspects of Torah.

My first comment got deleted apparently. You clearly are not familiar. And pshat does not include all 3. Show me the Rashi; you are certainly misunderstanding it.
